# Selenium webdriver how to get the enabled status of an angularjs Li element

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath

I have the following `angular.js` on a page. The items being displayed are `angular.js` `Li` items. One is greyed out the other is enabled. When I use the `Selenium webdriver` method `.isEnabled()`, both the greyed out and enabled items return "enabled".

The first question is how do I get `.isEnabled()` to work with this type of element?
Q
The second question is, assuming webdriver won't do it and I need to `xpath`, I guess I could use something like this:

```
$x("//li[@class ='ng-scope disabled' and @id='actionCUSTARD']")
$x("//li[@class ='ng-scope' and @id='actionRHUBARB']")
```

The first returns something only if the given id is disabled, the second only if the given Id is enabled, this could be built into a Java method to check that for a given id the element is enabled or disabled.  Is there an easier way of doing this?

```
</li>
<li id="actionRHUBARB" class="ng-scope" on="deriveInvokeType(action)" ng-switch="" ng-class="{'disabled': false}" ng-repeat="action in getActionList()">
    <!--
     ngSwitchWhen: LINK_DYNAMIC
    -->
    <!--
     ngSwitchWhen: NO_INVOKE_PERMISSION
    -->
    <!--
     ngSwitchDefault: 
    -->
    <a class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="doAction(action)" ng-switch-default="" href=""></a>
</li>
<li id="actionCUSTARD" class="ng-scope disabled" on="deriveInvokeType(action)" ng-switch="" ng-class="{'disabled': true}" ng-repeat="action in getActionList()">
    <!--
     ngSwitchWhen: LINK_DYNAMIC
    -->
    <!--
     ngSwitchWhen: NO_INVOKE_PERMISSION
    -->
    <!--
     ngSwitchDefault: 
    -->
    <a class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="doAction(action)" ng-switch-default="" href=""></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The element is probably disabled with the style `pointer-events` set to `none` which is not considered by `.isEnabled()`. If it's the case you could evaluate the CSS value returned by `.getCssValue`:

```java
boolean isEnabled = !"none".equals(element.getCssValue("pointer-events"));
```

Or with a piece of JavaScript:

```java
boolean isEnabled = (boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null).getPropertyValue('pointer-events') === 'none'"
    , element);
```

You could also determine the state by checking the presence of the class `disable`, but it won't guarantee that the element is disabled by the implemented style.

Answer (score 0):

According to Your first question you can simply get element using `By.id` and check `isEnabled()` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("actionRHUBARB"))
```

or

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("actionCUSTARD"))
```

and check for enabled as :-

```
if(el.isEnabled()) {
   //do your stuff
}
```

**Note** :- `findElement` always gives you element if it is present on the `DOM` otherwise it will throws `NoSuchElementException`

Now according to your second question if selenium failed to find `enabled` element, you can use `By.cssSelector` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(":not(.disabled)[id = 'actionRHUBARB']"));
//it will find enabled element with id actionRHUBARB

WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(":not(.disabled)[id = 'actionCUSTARD']"));
//it will throw NoSuchElementException because it is not enabled
```

Hope it helps...:)